# How to override default panTo behaviour on marker click in Google Map Api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

By default when you click on a marker the map pans to that location.

When I click on a marker, I want the map to center on a different location (a nearby point I have calculated).

The problem is that after the map moves to the desired location, it moves again to center on the clicked marker.

I want to override this behaviour, I want the map pan to the desired location and stay there ignoring that the marker was clicked.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.panTo(differentLatLng);
});
```

I tried adding a "return false" to the event handler, but the default handling persists.

Comment: Please show an example, because it does not happen here http://jsfiddle.net/g597E/

Comment: Accoding to your example this should not happen. Mmm, I don't have anything online to show. And the code I have is to big and spread to paste here. I'll try to reproduce the problem with a smaller example when I have time to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this while still creating a custom infoWindow via maker click listener, so this might help.

infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({disableAutoPan: true});

Eric

Comment: I'm actually using infobubble.js (http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobubble/src/infobubble.js?r=206). I found the problem myself a couple of hours before, but I had to wait 8 hours before answering my own question (reputation below 100). So there you go.